# Position image properly with text

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a picture display inline with text on it's right, AND at the same time positioned in the middle of the vertical axis to fit in the navigation bar.

At the moment, I can only get it to display inline but it always verges to the bottom of the bar rather than the top.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='profileBar'>
 <img src='karl.png' width=25 id='profileBarPic'/>
 Damen
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#profileBar {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#profileBarPic {
    width: 25px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

What it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

Comment: Can't you just change it with adding a small margin-bottom to only the picture? (It's just a guess because it's hard to see where the problem is, a jsfiddle would be handy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text next to an image? That's how images have always worked. You can get the desired affect with a lot less markup:

```
<div id='profileBar'>
  <img src='http://placekitten.com/50/50' id='profileBarPic'/>
  Damen
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#profileBarPic {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFWTd/)

A little explanation. `img` is basically an inline element to begin with, so adding `float` and `display: inline` is not necessary.

By default `img` [aligns with the baseline of its container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img#Interaction_with_CSS) (the bottom edge of an image will align with the bottom of a text line it is next to). `vertical-align` changes where the `img` should align itself to (in this case, you wanted the middle).

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading a fiddle next time, I think this should fix it though:

```
#profilebar {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your text into a span or something so that you can put a `display:inline-block` on both it and the `<img>`. This way, you won't need the `float:left`. Then apply a `vertical-align:middle`

so:

HTML:

```
<div id='profileBar'>
 <img src='karl.png' width='25' id='profileBarPic'/>
 <span>Damen</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#profileBar {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#profileBar span {display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
#profileBarPic {
    width: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```